# Complex but Simple equation.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

Im( e^z ) = 1

I've reached rsin(t) = 1 but I am stuck here,
where r is radius and t is argument.

There may be use of logs here I might be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $z=a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\Im\left(e^{a+bi}\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\Re\left(ie^{a+bi}\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$i\left(-e^{a+bi}+\Re\left(e^{a+bi}\right)\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-ie^{a+bi}+i\Re\left(e^{a+bi}\right)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-ie^{a+bi}+ie^a\cos(b)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^a\sin(b)=1$$

---

Solving the last part we get:

$$a=\ln\left(\csc(b)\right)+2i\pi n$$
$$b=\pi-\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{e^a}\right)+2\pi n\space\space\vee\space\space b=\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{e^a}\right)+2\pi n$$

With $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

$$Im(e^{x+yi})=e^x\sin y=1\\
x=-\ln (\sin y)\\
z=-\ln (\sin t)+ti$$

Comment: How do I shade the regions on the graph for this solution?